# Using R radiant, issues with MathJax

Tags: r, shiny

I've installed radiant, and have updated my R studio and R to the latests versions. Yet I'm still receiving this strange "mathjax" error.

```
 withMathJax()
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="/www/MathJax/": No such file or directory
```

Any ideas to correct this?

More info on the error:

Error when trying to run Radiant:
I see this in the browser (chrome)
   ERROR: path[1]="/www/MathJax/": No such file or directory

i see this on the command line
     radiant("marketing")
     Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7160
     Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
     path[1]="/www/MathJax/": No such file or directory
     Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
     path[1]="/www/MathJax/": No such file or directory

Info:
RStudio
Version 0.99.465 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.

> R.Version()
>   $platform
>   [1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.1"

$year
[1] "2015"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "18"

$`svn rev`
[1] "68531"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)"

$nickname
[1] "World-Famous Astronaut"

> packageVersion("radiant")
>   [1] ‘0.1.83’

Comment: You can file issues for Radiant here: https://github.com/vnijs/radiant/issues When you post an issue please provide more information on the error and when it occured (i.e., more lines around the error message). Also let me know what version of Radiant you are using (i.e., the output from `packageVersion("radiant")`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reinstalling this package and shiny, and reseting everything, errors no longer persisted.